# Ubuntu run service in foreground

Tags: bash, ubuntu, service, docker

I've made a (docker) container for [ddclient](https://github.com/MLoureiro/docker/tree/master/ddclient).

The problem is that I'm having problems in running that service in the foreground so that the docker container keeps running.

I've managed to keep the docker running by adding a `bash`at the end of the [script](https://github.com/MLoureiro/docker/blob/master/ddclient/start.sh#L27) but this is hackish, since the actual process it should be whatching is the ddclient.

Another way I found was to `tail -f` the log file, but if the service stops, the container will keep running instead of stoping.

**Q:** So is there any (easy) way to keep a service running in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the process (any process) running in a container is signal management: you need to make sure the SIGKILL and other signals are properly communicated to the right process(es) in order to successfully stop/remove a container (and not leave zombie processes: see "[PID 1 zombie reaping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309)")

One option is at least to make your service at least write in a log file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh" "-c" ]
CMD  yourProcess > log
```

That should keep it in foreground, as suggested in "[How do I bring a daemon process to foreground?](https://serverfault.com/a/41013/783)".

For a service, try and use as a base image [`phusion/baseimage-docker`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which manages other services properly.

Comment: I'm starting the process as ubuntu service, like `service ddclient start` so, this doesn't any output

Comment: @mloureiro I have eidted the answer

Comment: Thanks @VonC, but I'm already using that image... After reading all that, and actually take a look at the *my_init* script. I don't understand how this is supposed to help me. And about the daemon `mydaemon > /var/log/mydaemonlogfile`  if I do `service ddclient start > /var/log/ddclient.log` how does this help?

Comment: @mloureiro It helps the process staying in foreground. But if the service start ends immediately, that won't help. Could you do (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26735742/6309) a `service ddclient start && service supervisor start`?

Comment: @mloureiro that base image should still being able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775424/6309. "runit will stay online while Nginx and Supervisor run" (in your case while ddclient runs)

Comment: I don't have `supervisor` on the container, should it come with `baseimage` or do I need to install it?

Comment: @mloureiro you don't need to the supervisor, just to us the https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker and its runit main service: you can declare ddclient as a service.

Comment: i'm using `phusion/baseimage:0.9.18` how can I *declare ddclient as a service* ?

Comment: @mloureiro As documented: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding_additional_daemons