# Nginx in Docker terminates directly

Tags: nginx, docker

I created a docker image based on nginx and included the config in the image it self.

ThenI start the container (`docker run -p 2000:80 nginx_be:0.1`). 
When I don't check for running containers with  `docker ps` there are none.

What am I missing?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
ADD /conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
WORKDIR /etc/nginx
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest [nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/c769ad8ab21dfb374fa33d8fb9d0822d0fa8d2e5/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile#L43) does end with:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

You should do the same in order to avoid nginx launching as a daemon (background), which would make the container stop immediately (because of the lack of a foreground process).
See also "[How to Keep Docker Container Running After Starting Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735742/6309)".

You can also see [this docker run command](http://www.dennyzhang.com/process_foreground/) which override your Dockerfile `CMD`:

```
docker run -t -d --name my-nginx nginx /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: @BoasEnkler Yes, I have also edited the answer to highlight a way to test that command without editing the Dockerfile/building your image first.