# why does docker prune not remove my dangling images?

Tags: docker

Tthe docs say docker prune "removes all dangling images". And it even issues a warning "this will remove all dangling images". So why does it not remove mine?

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-48:~$ docker image prune
WARNING! This will remove all dangling images.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0 B
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-48:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
simonm3/registrm    latest              bd3ef6d73785        7 minutes ago       468 MB
simonm3/registr     latest              7dd15943671b        2 hours ago         2.51 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              f8f22986e85a        45 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              c1b9d8606371        45 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              f1ca97467106        45 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registr     <none>              6a5af88f93a7        45 hours ago        4.42 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              93dc81b0fa7a        45 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              dbc50510d499        45 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registr     <none>              0101ca5d4a25        45 hours ago        4.42 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              d8f85df39f0a        46 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              053892e9798b        46 hours ago        2.93 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              3845056cf241        46 hours ago        2.92 GB
simonm3/registr     <none>              349ef3c589bd        46 hours ago        4.42 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              5dcbb0db4710        2 days ago          2.92 GB
simonm3/registr     <none>              e403f74861f6        2 days ago          4.32 GB
simonm3/registr     <none>              c12ca8819c24        5 days ago          4.32 GB
simonm3/registrm    <none>              4bb8ed8154b7        6 days ago          2.92 GB
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-48:~$ docker images -q -f dangling=true
f8f22986e85a
c1b9d8606371
f1ca97467106
6a5af88f93a7
93dc81b0fa7a
dbc50510d499
0101ca5d4a25
d8f85df39f0a
053892e9798b
3845056cf241
349ef3c589bd
5dcbb0db4710
e403f74861f6
c12ca8819c24
4bb8ed8154b7
```

Comment: what docker version are u using?

Comment: Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:45:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

Answer (score 32):

My problem was that I misunderstood what "dangling image" actually meant. I wanted to delete all *unused* images, not just the *dangling* images.

- **An unused image** is one that is not currently assigned to any container.
- **A dangling image** is one that has not been tagged. Remember that Docker images are identified by their sha256 digests, not their tags.

I actually wanted to remove all unused Docker images, which you would need to use `-a`/`--all` for.

```
$ docker help image prune

Usage:  docker image prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused images

Options:
  -a, --all             Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'until=<timestamp>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
```

So in other words, the solution for me was:

```
$ docker image prune -a
```

Answer (score 19):

Docker won't prune dangling images that still have containers, even if they're no longer running. Use `docker container prune` to remove stopped containers, first, then `docker image prune` will remove dangling images the pruned containers relied on.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because these are probably intermediary images for some image building.

Therefore not really dangling images.

Comment: They are listed as dangling in the last command issued above. They are old versions of the two "latest" images. Definitely dangling.

Comment: Just asking - is it ok to leave intermediate images that appears as none when running `docker images -a`? Or should we delete them? How to check their size and how to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove all those images tagged with `<none>` the `docker rmi` command will refuse (even when forced with `-f`), claiming they are used in other child images:

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | grep '<none>' | awk '{print $3}' | head -10) 
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete e6da252e9c6d (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete acfa42da25c4 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9b0ab509f17e (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 60be66128f80 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 5806afd2a6d2 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete cb0db4d86d68 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete a55dc64b78d0 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete cf9654bfcfbd (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete bedcaa9e433f (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1e113b1d7a73 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

The only working method is a destructive one - to remove all non-running containers using `docker system prune -a`, but wait, there is a **workaround** - **first start (via `docker run`) all useful containers that you want to keep before your run that `docker system prune -a` command**, as it won't remove images used in running containers. If you forget to start those useful containers (and keep them running, if necessary with an infinite loop, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775266/how-to-keep-docker-container-running-after-starting-services)), it is likely that after `system prune -a` finishes, the number of all container images (including not just the dangling ones) returned by `docker images -a | wc -l` will be exactly zero.