# Why docker system prune did not remove the dangling images while docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc) did

Tags: docker

This is the first time I hit the situation that `docker system prune` did not remove the dandling images. After running `docker system prune` I still have many images has the tag `<none>`.

`docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc`  removed them, but why ?

BTW, those  images were create when I pull the new ones with the same tags. There is another SO [why does docker prune not remove my dangling images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620016/why-does-docker-prune-not-remove-my-dangling-images) talking about the similar problem but I don't think we were the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might there still be containers based on those images?

If not: It seems that `docker system prune` doesn’t consider images without a tag as dangling. More on that can be found here: [Moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30307#issuecomment-274616724)

Try: `docker system prune -a`

Comment: Found a similar problem on https://gist.github.com/anildigital/862675ec1b7bccabc311#gistcomment-2274889 but without a real solution either.

Comment: The images having name and tag as none in `docker images` are dangled. How to check their size? Also, the images having name and tag as none in `docker images -a` are intermediate images. Can they be deleted and how to check their size?