# GitLab CI/CD SSH Session Hangs in Pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab CI/CD to build and push a docker image to my private GitLab registry.

I am able to successfully SSH into my server from the pipeline runner, but any commands passed into the SSH session doesn't run.

I am trying to pull the latest image from my GitLab container registry, run it, and exit the session to gracefully (successfully) pass the data to my pipeline.

The command I am running is:

```
ssh -t user@123.456.789 "docker pull registry.gitlab.com/user/project:latest & docker run project:latest"
```

The above command connects me to my server, and I see the typical welcome message, but the session hangs and no commands are ran.

I have tried using the `heredoc` format to pass in multiple commands at once, but I can't get a single command to work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: & will background the process, && will chain the processes if process 1 exits with a successful return code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing, you can try

```
ssh user@123.456.789 ls
```

To chain command, avoid using the '`&`', which [would make the first command run in the background, while acting as command separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451502/7490).

Try:

```
ssh user@123.456.789 "ls; pwd"
```

If this work, then try the two `docker` command, separated by '`;`'

Try with a [`docker run -td`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872226/6309) (that [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209974/6309)) in order to detach the docker process, without requiring a tty.

Comment: When trying `ssh -t user@123.456.789 "ls; pwd` the ssh connection still sits at the motd screen and has no output.

Comment: @confusedandamused did you close the "? I see "ls;pwd in your comment, not "ls; pwd"

Comment: @ssh try ssh without -t: that would allocate a TTY.

Comment: That worked wonderful!  Is there a simple way to gracefully end the ssh session - leaving the image running?  (So the CI/CD job passes?)

Comment: in both cases with or without -t ,having  issue of randomly hanging , it does not return the control to next command....

Comment: @NiazHussain strange, could you try and ask a separate question, for us to have a look?

Comment: @VonC, here it is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565543/gitlab-ci-ssh-remote-commands-hangging-randomly-when-copying-files-from-runner-h)