# gitlab-ci ssh remote commands hangging randomly when copying files from runner host to remote host

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running `rsync -Parz myfile  remoteuser@remotehost:targetpath/`
and

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remoteuser@remotehost << HERE
        somecommands here to start service etc
    HERE
```

using gitlab-ci pipeline and executing above commands through `.gitlab-ci.yml` and it randomly hangs but most of the time it works.

My objective is to copy some files  and execute some commands from gitlab-runner on remote host.