# What is tail command with docker run entrypoint in visual studio 2019?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

I am running Windows 10 pro, docker installed and linux containers.

With Visual Studio 2019, I created a basic .net core web api app, and enabled docker support(linux).

I built the solution, and in the output window (View -> Output or Ctrl + Alt + O) I selected "Container Tools" in the Show Output From drop down. Scroll till the end(see the scroll bar in the below image)
 and you see the entry point option to the docker run command as follows.

```
--entrypoint tail webapp:dev -f /dev/null
```

The entire docker run command for your ref is as follows.

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\MyUserName\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDocker\src\WebApp:/app" -v "D:\Trials\Docker\VsDocker\src:/src" -v "C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -P --name WebApp --entrypoint tail webapp:dev -f /dev/null
```

So my question is what is this "tail". I saw two so questions([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42873832/1977871) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42873832/1977871)) but could not get much. Also from [here](https://shapeshed.com/unix-tail/), tail seems to be a linux command(and I am running a linux container) but what does it do here?

Please enlighten me.

[image]

Comment: what does it do here? You mean in the container or in general what the command `tail -f /dev/null` does?

Comment: In the container what is the purpose of it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Entrypoint is the binary that is being executed.
Example: `--entrypoint=bash` `--entrypoint=helm` like this.
The `tail` linux utility displays the contents of file or, by default, its standard input, to the standard output `/dev/null`.
`/dev/null` redirects the command standard output to the null device, which is a special device which discards the information written to it. So when you run a `tail -f /dev/null` in a terminal it prints nothing.

**If you would like to keep your container running in detached mode, you need to run something in the foreground. An easy way to do this is to `tail` the `/dev/null` device as the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command of your Docker image.**

Comment: You mean to say its same as '-it', in the command docker run --rm -it webapp:dev

Comment: `-it` takes you straight inside the container only when you mention the executables in the end of your command. like `docker run -it --rm nginx:stable bash` gets me to a bash tty for further interacting with the container. In your docker run command, you say it to keep running in detached mode with `-d` option. Having entrypoint to `tail -f /dev/null` doesn't shutdown the container.

Comment: So, how do we get it to not include this? -- It's keeping my containers alive indefinitely, even after the service's process has ended.

Comment: Please explain your issue clearly or write a new query. @BrainSlugs83